# Do I need to install all the drivers for my Laptop?

Tags: drivers, laptop

I am using HP Mini Laptop. I am going to replace my Windows 7 OS with Ubuntu. Do I need to install all the supporting drivers (Like we do after installing Windows) of my Laptop(Graphic, WiFi, Bluetooth etc.,) after installing Ubuntu?

Comment: You can try the live CD and check if it works

Comment: Download the Ubuntu "image" ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop ), "burn" it to DVD ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows ) or setup a bootable "thumb" drive ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows ), restart your computer ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install )... If you're happy with everything, install it ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop ). Ubuntu should automatically work with most of your hardware - if something doesn't work though, just ask here...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the time, all the drivers you would need are built into the Linux Kernel, however there are some proprietary drivers that would have to be installed post-installation of Ubuntu ( System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers ) .